# Is it possible to secure the linux kernel sockets?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

- I have several Linux applications which uses sockets (UDP/TCP IP).
- I want (need, no matter why) to secure the connection with my own secure protocol without changing those applications.
- I thought about changing the Linux kernel socket implementation, so I can use my secure protocol sockets, without changing those applications.
- So, Is it possible to change the Linux kernel sockets, so when using send or receive sockets function, the inner Linux implementation will by mine ? 
  And how can I do it ? which kernel module do I need to change ?

Comment: You don't need to modify the linux kernel for this. You can just use a [ssh tunnel](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information to provide meaningful answers. You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*